# Full calendar drag listener when drag event

Tags: fullcalendar

When drag external event I use draggable and option drag. Then I get information every move. Now I need the same for internal event, but are availabe only dragStart and dragStop, which run only one times.

----SOLVED----

I use eventAllow in Fullcalendar

Comment: what do you mean by "every move"...what kind of information precisely do you wish to capture?

Comment: Ok. I need position dragged event in scheduler, because at the beginnig and end I can add line on all height. If I dragged external event I use jquery ui method draggeble. When I use option drag with function I get position event from scheduler.